# Expression Engine - Pass loop variable into embeded template

Tags: expressionengine

have some trouble with Expression Engine variable passing in templates.

There is some piece of code:

// query:

```
{exp:channel:entries
  channel="static"
}
```

// repeating field in a loop

```
{content_matrix}
   <div>
      {text_cell}
   </div>    
   {image}
{/content_matrix}
```

//

```
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I want to move content_matrix field with big inner HTML (example is shorter) sctructure into separate embed template for reusage in other templates.

Tried to build such embed but it doesnt work:

```
{embed="incl/content_matrix" matrix="{content_matrix}"}
```

And body of smaller template:

```
 {embed:matrix}
   <div>
      {text_cell}
   </div>    
   {image}
 {/embed:matrix}
```

In this way it works if you passing single element, like ID, but not for mupltiple element.
Maybe it needs to pass entire entry.

How it can be done?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Have you considered using the [Stash add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/stash)?

I imagine you can stash the matrix content dividing between different parts of your html with some kind of separator, then in the embedded template wrap [a search/replace](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/phpstringfun) for the separators with the proper html around the grabbed stash.

It might be less of a pain to write a quick, custom plugin, though.

Comment: Thanks Tyssen! Edited to add-on, probably what I meant initially.

Answer (score 3):

[Embed variables](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/embedding.html#embed-variables-for-the-embedded-template) pass parsed output, not tags. So in your example:

```
{embed="incl/content_matrix" matrix="{content_matrix}"}
```

What you're actually passing in the `matrix` parameter is the full HTML table output of the data in that particular entry (since Matrix fields output a table when used as a single tag).

I think what you actually want to use to prevent repeating yourself is a [Snippet](http://expressionengine.com/user_guide/templates/globals/snippets.html). So just make a snippet containing:

```
{content_matrix}
   <div>
      {text_cell}
   </div>    
   {image}
{/content_matrix}
```

And save it as, say, **matrix_loop**. Then include it inside your Channel Entries loop like so:

```
{matrix_loop}
```

Comment: don't like snippets. I'd like to put it inside template :) Ok, so if Matrix field is passed as HTML, maybe i can pass entry to template and then loop through Matrix field, or in some other way?

Comment: What's wrong with Snippets? The scenario you're describing is exactly what Snippets were created for. If it's because you can't work with them as files, there's always Mountee or SnippetSync or Libraree. That said, I'd definitely recommend checking out Stash, it's awesome.